# jQuery + PHP + MySQL: Drag 'n' Drop with 2 tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

to the point:

I have two tables next to each other.
One is filled with data (in this case, a table filled with names of all people working in a team).
The other one is empty. Now, I want to drag and drop the names (rows) in the other table, and **on the drop**, it triggers an **insert**-query to the database.

Also, the names in the first table, filled with data, always stays the same (as the list of names never change).

So, a little scheme:

1. Table filled with data coming from a database (drag)
2. Empty table (drop)

A name is being dragged from the first table to the second, and when dropped, an insert-query is issued to the database. On a refresh of the page, the dropped name will still be seen in the second table.

Oh, one more feature that optionally should be implemented: if I drag a name from the second table back to the first, the name should disappear (and as such drops the record from the table in the database). Drag and drop should be usable in both directions.

The code I already had, but is somehow not working:

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var $tabs = $('#EmptyTable')
                $("tbody.t_sortable").sortable({
                    connectWith: ".t_sortable",
                    items: "> tr:not(:first)",
                    appendTo: $tabs,
                    helper:"clone",
                    zIndex: 999990
                }).disableSelection();

                var $tab_items = $(".nav-tabs > li", $tabs).droppable({
                    accept: ".t_sortable tr",
                    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
                    drop: function( event, ui ) { 
                <?
                  mysql_query("INSERT INTO emptyTable_team (name) values (<datafromfirsttable>)");
?>
             return false; 
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't insert PHP functions into Javascript.

PHP is a scripting language that tells your webserver how to handle requests, such as updating a database or rendering HTML. But once the request has been handled the PHP script stops, all variables are unloaded, etc.

What you've scripted in PHP is telling Apache to run that query *once while the page loads*.

What you want to do is call [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) inside the drop function. jQuery's ajax function can POST data to a url, at which point you process the request by inserting the data into your database.

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $tabs = $('#EmptyTable');
  $("tbody.t_sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".t_sortable",
    items: "> tr:not(:first)",
    appendTo: $tabs,
    helper:"clone",
    zIndex: 999990
  }).disableSelection();

  var $tab_items = $(".nav-tabs > li", $tabs).droppable({
    accept: ".t_sortable tr",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
      var rowData;
      // looping through the cell of each row
      for (var i = 0; i < $("td",this).length; i++) {
        // Get the name of the column
        // I don't know your HTML so I can't make a selector for this
        var colName = $("selector-for-header-column").text(); 
        // Using square brackets to access an object property by string variable, 
        // and selecting the text in this cell for the dropped row.
        rowData[colName] = $("td",this).eq(i).text(); 
      }
      // Now we have an object whose property names are the table headers, 
      // and the data in each property is the text in each cell of the dropped row.
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/insertTeamMember.php",
        data: rowData,
        success: function (data) {
          // Log the return from the ajax endpoint, this will help you debug!
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**insertTeamMember.php:**

```
<?PHP
$dbcO = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$q = "INSERT INTO emptyTable_team (name) values ( ? )";
$stmt = $dbcO->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($q);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['name']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
?>
```

I've used a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) as a simple way of preventing mysql injection. It's highly recommended to never insert user input directly into a query string. User input being all data coming from a client.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer!
I'm just wondering: what do you mean by `var colName = $("selector-for-header-column").text()`: can you be more specific about the colName? 
After trying to use the example: the drag 'n' drop does work, but all the functions when dragging/dropping don't.

Comment: I don't know what your html structure is so I can't tell you what selector to write. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) is the documentation for the selector function used when selecting an element with $()

Comment: We're going to use a synchronize button instead of using the drop for putting things in the database. Thanks for the reaction tho, I'm sure that, with a little bit more knowledge, your method should work as well!